# After fresh install my laptop is still hosting on my router even with wifi disabled?

Tags: wireless, dell, localhost, 23.04, hosts

I have a Dell Inspiron N5010, did a fresh install via USB erasing the disck & using automatic applied settings (Did not have wifi or bluetooth on both soft/hard).
I did this because I my laptop keeps being bridged via multiple ip addresses on my home router (shared house of 8 people). They say my laptop comes up as the router & they connect to the internet via me??? Even when my laptop if off the wlan0 interface shows that it is up & active when I look via my mobile & even my mobile route shows internet access is via my laptop address even though I have never set it to be.
So a fresh install was done & wlan0 was not viable on the router untill the install completed, even though wifi etc off in bios & on switch!
Upon set up of latest desktop 23.04 it defaults instantly to me hosting the entire home network & connects itself to a local server I have not set up. How can this happen?
In logs it says things like activated backend esata bridge & lists 7 connected hosts but ***** out. When I turn on wifi a crypto server shows up on the system monitor & my laptop is 100%cpu 100% memory & is then not usable!
All this immediately after fresh install of a fresh new flash stick from ubuntu main site.
Is it bugged so deep I can't remove the buried scripts doing all this? HELP & ADVISE PLEASE

Comment: Slow down there, buckaroo. Turn off your WiFi and connect using a cable only. I've seen something like this before: The fellow had a weak password and left the hardware within reach of a housemate who promptly abused their trust.

Comment: Unable to duplicate: A test install of Ubuntu 23.04 desktop does not suddenly advertise itself as a router nor connect to crypto sites.